# React Native push notification using FCM and Java Web API?

Tags: java, react-native, push-notification

Currently I'm creating react-native apps. I have also developed Java Web API to support the apps. So now I want to send push notification from Java API to react-native app.

But I understand that Java API need to go through APNS & GCM to send notification to mobile apps. However as mentioned on Google website, GCM is deprecated and is replaced by the FCM. Now, FCM can send notification to both IOS and Android which mean I don't need APNS anymore?

My question is what is the proper way to do sending notification from Java API to mobile apps?

What are java libraries that can send push notifications using FCM?

How the react-native apps can accept push notifications, and what are the libraries for it, if let's say using only FCM?

I am assuming FCM can replace what I would need Java to handle both APNS and GCM.

I don't want FCM to directly send notification without using Java API as notification configuration is coming from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCM in both Android and IOS.

Simply create a java micro-service acting as a interface with FCM for sending notifications.

FCM allows you send notification by exposing an end-point for your app which uses FCM-KEY as authorisation,
you have to hit that API with correct payload for sending notification.

Check out this link - http://www.sourcecodematrix.com/2017/08/how-to-send-push-notifications-using.html